# Making Multithreading Pool working inside a Class

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to get this code to work under a class, but how could i do it?

Actual Working code:

```
import multiprocessing
from datetime import datetime



def get_list():
    the_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
    return the_list

def print_list(names):

    for result in names:

        print "%s\t%s" % (multiprocessing.current_process().name,result)

def start_process():
    print 'Starting', multiprocessing.current_process().name

def mp_handler():

    data = get_list()
    print "Pool size    :", len(data)
    pool_size = 1
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=pool_size, initializer=start_process)
    p.map(print_list, data)
    p.close()
    p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = datetime.now()

    mp_handler()
    print "runtime : %s" % (datetime.now() - start_time)
```

Output:

```
Pool size    : 3
Starting PoolWorker-1
PoolWorker-1    a
PoolWorker-1    b
PoolWorker-1    c
runtime : 0:00:00.458000

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What i tried to do , but i'm getting error:

```
import multiprocessing
from datetime import datetime


class m_test():

    def __init__(self):
        this_mod='some test'

    def get_list(self):
        the_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
        return the_list

    def print_list(self, names):

        for result in names:

            print "%s\t%s" % (multiprocessing.current_process().name,result)

    def start_process(self):
        print 'Starting', multiprocessing.current_process().name

    def mp_handler(self):

        data = self.get_list()
        print "Pool size    :", len(data)
        pool_size = 1
        p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=pool_size, initializer=self.start_process)
        p.map(self.print_list, data)
        p.close()
        p.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = datetime.now()
    start = m_test()
    start.mp_handler()
    print "runtime : %s" % (datetime.now() - start_time)
```

Output :

```
Pool size    : 3
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 761, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 342, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message indicates, the problem is that an instance method can't be pickled, which the`multiprocessing`module requires being able to do in order to operate with instances your class. To pass arguments to a multiprocessing`Process`the argument must be able to be serialized using pickle.

A simple workaround is to define global functions corresponding to each of the methods of the instance that needs to be invoked. These "helper" functions will have to have an instance passed to them so they can forward the call on to the proper object (as well as potentially retrieve any arguments doing so might require). Here's what I mean:

**The significant revision in this version,** made to address the question you asked in a comment about why the previous version wasn't running more than one process at a time from the`Pool`, was to add a`maxtasksperchild`keyword argument to the creation of the`multiprocessing.Pool`. Setting this makes it (re)start worker/child processes after they have finished at most the number of tasks specified -- because by default, even though`Pool`creates a`processes=pool_size`number of them,`map()`will attempt to call the function in the same one for each item in the iterable.

```
import multiprocessing
from datetime import datetime

class M_Test():
    def __init__(self):
        this_mod='some test'

    def get_list(self):
        the_list = ["a", "b", "c"]
        return the_list

    def print_list(self, names):
        print("%s\tprint_list(%r) called" % ( # added statement
                                  multiprocessing.current_process().name,names))
        for result in names:
            print("%s\t  processing %r" % (multiprocessing.current_process().name,result))

    def start_process(self):
        print('Starting %s' % multiprocessing.current_process().name)

    def mp_handler(self):
        data = self.get_list()
        pool_size = 1
        print("Pool size    : %s" % pool_size)
        p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=pool_size,
                                 initializer=initializer, initargs=(self,),
                                 maxtasksperchild=1)  # additional keyword arg
        p.map(print_list, (self,)*len(data))
        p.close()  # don't create any more tasks
        p.join()   # finish all currently running ones

# "helper" functions
def initializer(inst):
    inst.start_process()

def print_list(inst):
    inst.print_list(inst.get_list())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = datetime.now()
    start = M_Test()
    start.mp_handler()
    print("runtime : %s" % (datetime.now() - start_time))
```

Output:

```
Pool size    : 1
Starting PoolWorker-1
PoolWorker-1    print_list(['a', 'b', 'c']) called
PoolWorker-1      processing 'a'
PoolWorker-1      processing 'b'
PoolWorker-1      processing 'c'
Starting PoolWorker-2
PoolWorker-2    print_list(['a', 'b', 'c']) called
PoolWorker-2      processing 'a'
PoolWorker-2      processing 'b'
PoolWorker-2      processing 'c'
Starting PoolWorker-3
PoolWorker-3    print_list(['a', 'b', 'c']) called
PoolWorker-3      processing 'a'
PoolWorker-3      processing 'b'
PoolWorker-3      processing 'c'
runtime : 0:00:01.219000
```

The output isn't quite the same as from your non-class based version, but I believe it's likely to be what you would really want to see happening. I also changed the print statements a bit in an effort to provide clearer information about what's going on.

Comment: The "print "Pool size :", len(data)"  was just to output more info :)

Comment: Well, something like `print "Pool size    :", pool_size` would have accomplished the same thing as well as provide accurate and potentially useful info. As for the multiple passing of `self` to `p.map()`: There's only one instance of a `class M_Test` object around to pass it. I'm somewhat mystified that the `multiprocessing.Pool.map()` function doesn't initialize multiple `Pool` processes -- but it doesn't in your non-class based version either (set its `pool_size = 3` to see). I'll look into this more and update my answer if I figure out what's wrong with my understanding.

Comment: I'm still into this also, but thanks a lot for helping on this question =)

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't accepted my answer? Seems to me like it addresses your core question.